# Installed iso over the harddrive and how to boot from grub. Installation wont start

Tags: boot

Hi i installed a iso file or lubuntu wrong and had chosed to installed it over the hard drive instead of the usb i waa supposed to,  so when i start my compter it boots directly to the live cd menu (try ubuntu without installng or install ubuntu etc) and when trying both it fails and when at startup i first get a error that tells me to restart and report the problem, installation wont starts at all and wont come up. I have the option to enter grub by pressing esc at boot to enter grub. How can i install by grub or boot inio my old installation?

Comment: If you wrote the iso image onto your hard disk, your old installation there is destroyed and recovering anything would be pretty infeasible. (Most of the data except for the first GB will still be on the disk, but the file system is wiped out so you would not be able to tell what file some recoverable data fragments would have belonged to.) You also most likely can not boot the installer from your HDD to install Ubuntu onto the same disk. The easiest thing would be to make an Ubuntu installer USB or DVD on a different computer and then reinstall the system.

Comment: I alao have a sd card with iso wroten onto, but the installation wont start, how can i meaybe use grub to install

Comment: Not all PCs allow booting from a SD card. Internal SD card readers typically can't be used for that, USB ones usually can (but there are exceptions). If you have an USB SD card reader you may try that, otherwise don't bother and obtain a normal USB flash drive for the purpose.

Comment: Is there anothing i can do?